# Python pyodbc loop - remove brackets, hyphens and commas from list

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm using the below Python script to loop around a SQL Server table and save the values to a list.
However, I don't want the brackets \ commas etc.  When I run the below the records in the list look like this:

```
('TN12345', )
```

I just want the below - how it exists in the SQL table:

```
TN12345
```

This is my script:

```
import pyodbc

connstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=XXXXXXXXXXX;DATABASE=XXXXXXXXXXX;Trusted_Connection=yes;'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""SELECT TN_Number FROM Table""")

records = cursor.fetchall()
insertObject = []
columnNames = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]

for record in records:
    insertObject.append( dict( zip( columnNames , record ) ) )

for i in range(len(records)):
  print(records[i])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
('TN12345', )
```

is tuple with one element, representing row in database, if you can guarantee that your query will always return exactly 1 column then you might use `[0]` to access single element in said tuple, in your case replace

```
for i in range(len(records)):
  print(records[i])
```

using

```
for i in range(len(records)):
  print(records[i][0])
```

alternatively you might use `for` loop directly (without caring about index) in following way

```
for record in records:
  print(record[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all elements one by one in your tuples:

```
for i in range(len(records)):
    for j in records[i]:
        print(j)
```

Advantage is it will return every entry in your tuples no matter the length of the tuple or the length of the list of tuples.